# Compact way of having the same public key for many server ids in ssh known_hosts

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication

The known_hosts file has entries in the format of:

```
{server-id} {signature-algorithm} {public-key-string} {comment}
```

I work with the system that has many machines that share the same *{public-key-string}* but have many, almost 7000, different *{server-ids}*, I was wondering is it possible to make entries more compact?

I know I could specify all of them comma-separated like:

```
{server-id1},{server-id2},... {signature-algorithm} {public-key-string} {comment}
```

but there are almost 7000 of such {server-ids} with their IPs and aliases.

The naming schema of {server-ids} is something like:

```
a01b01c01d01
a01b01c01d02
...
a01b01c02d01
...
a08b11c06d12
```

Is some compact syntax for known_hosts available? Such as:

```
a[01-08]b[01-11]c[01-06]d[01-12] {signature-algorithm} {public-key-string} {comment}
```

Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Once I submitted the question, I noticed that there is an entry on a similar file (ssh_known_hosts) file in the manual of sshd.

```
man sshd
```

The manual states:

> Hostnames is a comma-separated list of patterns (‘*’ and ‘?’ act as
>   wildcards); each pattern in turn is matched against the canonical host
>   name (when authenticating a client) or against the user-supplied name
>   (when authenticating a server).  A pattern may also be preceded by ‘!’
>   to indicate negation: if the host name matches a negated pattern, it
>        is not accepted (by that line) even if it matched another pattern on the line.  A hostname or address may optionally be enclosed within
>   ‘[’ and ‘]’ brackets then followed by ‘:’ and a non-standard port
>   number.

Since the file format of ssh_known_hosts matches known_hosts, the answer to my question is by using wildcards:

```
a0?b??c0?d??,192.168.*.* {signature-algorithm} {public-key-string} {comment}
```

However, this still does not restrict only values I wanted to have, therefore if someone knows how to restrict it further please let me know.

a0?b??c0?d?? can also be a0ibx3c0wdxy